# Comparing the list in Class -VB

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have list which will select all field's from sql database and store it in a list

I have another list with the newly downloading file with their file ids.(File ID are unique)

Now I want compare these two list so that the newly downloaded values will be saved to database only if the fileId is not existing in the database.ie   File ID 5 is there in database and File ID 5 is downloaded again by the window service,It will not be saved in the database, Hence there will be no duplicate records with same file ID.Thank u very much

**Checking from db**

```
      cmd1.Connection = con1
    cmd1.CommandText = "select FileID from FileMaster"
    drd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    If drd1.HasRows = True Then
        Do While drd1.Read
            Fledbobj.MessageID = drd1.Item("FileID")
            List.Add(Filedbobj)
        Loop
     End If
```

**adding the downloading file in to List**

```
              For i = 1 To numfile
                'adding
                FileRecObj = New clsFileRec

                     FileRecOj .From = F.From
                     FileRecObj.FileDate = F.Date

                End If

                List.Add(FileRecObj)
            Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a linq query.

Create a list of string that contains all the ID: 
`IDList`

Create the list of downloaded files:

```
DownloadedList
```

Then create a new list from a linq query like so:

```
Dim NoDupeList = (From X in DownloadedList where Not IDList.Contains(X.FileID)).ToList()
```

Comment: cmd1.CommandText = "select * from FileRecOj Where Not List.contains(Filedbobj)).ToList()"
        drd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
       
            If drd1.HasRows = True Then
                Do While drd1.Read
                    checkobj.FileID = drd1.Item("FileID")
                    List.Add(checkFileobj)
                Loop
            End If

Comment: The code above is not meant to be executed using CommandText.  Its part of LINQ and uses the list as a datasource.  Take a look here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384667.aspx